# Parsing XML web request with sub-element via @RequestBody

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I need to parse such XML document in my Spring Boot application:

```
<Transaction id="{ID}" vs="{VS}" uniq="{UNIQ}">
<Data field1="{VAL1}" field2="{VAL2}" />
</Transaction>
```

This is endpoint method in my `@RestController`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transaction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ApiClient transaction(@RequestBody TransactionRequest transactionRequest) {
        LOGGER.debug(transactionRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

and `Transaction` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Transaction")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso(TransactionRequestData.class)
public class TransactionRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @XmlElement(name = "vs")
    private String vs;

    @XmlElement(name = "uniq")
    private String uniq;

    @XmlElement(name = "data")
    private TransactionRequestData data;
}
```

and `TransactionRequestData`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TransactionRequestData {

    @XmlElement(name = "field1")
    private String field1;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}
```

But this bound only `Transaction` element data but no `Data` element.

**Is there way how to parse sub-element?**

Answer (score 0):

The id,vs, uniq properties are xml attributes in your case.

Change the @XmlElement annotation with @XmlAttribute for the TransactionRequest pojo to the properties correctly.

Using the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Transaction")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso(TransactionRequestData.class)
public class TransactionRequest {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "vs")
    private String vs;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "uniq")
    private String uniq;

    @XmlElement(name = "data")
    private TransactionRequestData data;

    ....getters & setters ommited
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TransactionRequestData {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "field1")
    private String field1;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
     ....getters & setters ommited
}
```

And don't forget to include getters and setters for properties.

Comment: I've changed it but `TransactionRequest .data` is still null.

Comment: No, sorry, `id`, `vs` a `uniq` is filled but `data` filed is still null.